# Kendall's W for a series of answers about the same phenomenon in different entities

Tags: nonparametric, concordance

I have a question about the proper usage of Kendall's coefficient of concordance (Kendall's *W*). Suppose a series of questions were asked how democratic certain organisations are. Each question was the same for each organisation. There were five possible answers ranging from the most democratic to the most non-democratic. Can I in this case compute Kendall's *W*? If not, is there a technique that will measure the reliability of consensus that suits the case presented?

In every handbook I've checked there was no mention about such a case.
 Wikipedia's entry on [Kendall's *W*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall's_W) is no different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a reasonable application of Kendall's W.

It's important to understand how the statistic works.  It is related to Friedman's test, and sometimes the examples for Friedman's test you'll find are more useful than for Kendall's W.

In the following example, the raters are labeled a thru h.  The result is a small p-value (which should be the same as that for Friedman's test), and a large Kendall's W (0.599).  This is because raters tended to rate Burning.man higher or equal than IKEA, and rated IKEA higher or equal to Disneyland.  Note that the statistic treats the raters as blocks, so, essentially, what's important is the rating for each organization within each rater, (not the absolute scores for each organization as if you had independent observation as if you were using Kruskal-Wallis).

A toy example in R:

```
if(!require(DescTools)){install.packages("DescTools")}

Input =("
Organization     a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
  Disneyland     1  2  3  4  5  6  6  6
  IKEA           2  3  4  5  6  6  6  6
  Burning.man    3  4  5  6  6  6  6  6
")

Matrix = as.matrix(read.table(textConnection(Input),
                   header=TRUE, 
                   row.names=1))

Matrix

library(DescTools)

KendallW(Matrix,
         correct=TRUE,
         test=TRUE)

   ### Kendall's coefficient of concordance Wt

   ### data:  Matrix
   ### Kendall chi-squared = 9.5789, df = 2, subjects = 3, raters = 8, p-value = 0.008317
   ### alternative hypothesis: Wt is greater 0
   ### sample estimates:
   ###        Wt 
   ### 0.5986842
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this example and your clarifications.