# Correct interpretation of Kendall's W

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, concordance

This is a follow-up to my [earlier question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/333048/kendalls-w-for-a-series-of-answers-about-the-same-phenomenon-in-different-entit/333073#333073). Let me summarise what the original question dealt with. I asked whether I could compute Kendall's *W* for a case where the same question was asked for different entities. It asked the judges to assess how democratic certain organisations were. I was told that Kendall's *W* could be computed for that case. Please tell me whether my interpretation of the results is correct.

**UPDATED**

Below you can find the results computed in `R`.

```
Kendall chi-squared = 40.547, df = 3, subjects = 4, judges = 23, p-value = 8.159e-09
alternative hypothesis: Wt is greater 0
sample estimates:
       Wt 
0.5876359
```

The assessment of organization democracy by different judges were concordant to a low but satisfying degree (p < .005, Kendall's *W* = .59). In the case of `A organisation` most judges (15 out of 23) claimed it had conformed to fourth point of scale. `C organization` was deemed as more democratic than `A` organisation. In that case most often answer (10 out of 23) was the answer two. The third and fourth answer chose in each case five of the judges.

**UPDATE 2**

Here's my data:

```
Input = ("
Organization   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  R  S  T  U  W  X  Y
   Disneyland  4  4  4  4  3  4  2  4  3  5  4  5  2  3  5  2  2  3  4  4  3  4  4
   IKEA        3  4  2  1  3  2  1  4  2  2  4  4  2  2  3  2  1  2  2  3  4  2  3
   KFC         4  5  4  5  5  5  4  5  4  5  2  5  4  5  5  5  3  5  4  5  5  5  5
   Walmart     4  4  3  3  2  2  2  4  3  3  3  3  2  4  2  2  3  2  4  3  4  3  4
")
```

Comment: One thing you need to disentangle in your question:  The p-value determines if the results are statistically significant.  Kendall's W is a statistic for effect size, that says nothing about how "significant" the results are.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Please have a look at my updated question.

Comment: Also, you have "p > .005" instead of "<".

Comment: I updated my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your audience will probably not be very pleased with the phrase "to a low but satisfying degree".

The p-value either tests the null hypothesis that there was no difference among groups (Friedman's test) or that W = 0.  You didn't cite the code you are using, but I suspect that the tests for these two hypotheses are the same.  In either case, you have good evidence to reject the null hypothesis.

A Kendall's W of 0.6 is probably fairly large.  It's probably really large, [by my assessment](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/F_10.html), but I don't know of any established interpretation of Kendall's W. Any interpretation of an effect size is relative to the expectations of the analysis.  I guess in this case you were expecting a really high degree of concordance among raters.  You might want to rethink your expectations.  Where I live, you can't get 90% of americans to agree that the earth orbits the sun.

I think the way you are trying to explain the data ("15 out of 23" judges, and so on).  is good. One recommendation I have is to present the data for each organization as a histogram-like bar plot of values.  This ignores the effect of blocking by rater, but I think tells the story.  [It should look something like this](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/images/image067.png). If you have your data in long format, in R:

```
Data$Score.f = factor(Data$Score,
                      ordered=TRUE)
library(lattice)

histogram(~ Score.f | Organization,
          data=Data,
          layout=c(1,4)      #  columns and rows of individual plots
          )
```

Comment: Dear @Sal thanks for your input. As I'd like to be 100 % sure if I get all things right, I will get back to you with the code I used to compute the results. To be sure, it is your code, mine is data on democracy in organisations. I will change my description to take into account that "A Kendall's W of 0.6 is probably fairly large". What I very liked is the idea of histogram-like bar plots. If I get this correctly, they nicely summarise the ratings.

Comment: Yeah, there's no definitive interpretation of effect sizes.  I think they are very useful to report.  But it is often meaningful to include descriptive statistics and plots that your audience can interpret directly.  Medians, and perhaps other descriptive statistics;  histogram-like plots; percentages of ratings.

Comment: I updated my post with the code. I tried to run the first command from you answer but `R` shows error: `Error in factor(Data$Score, ordered = TRUE) : object 'Data' not found`. Do you know why?

Comment: Data would be your data frame with data in long form.

Comment: I tried `reshape` and `melt` but my knowledge of `R` is to limited to do so. Could you tell me how to do that, please?

Comment: This isn't the right forum for this conversation. Why not send me an email?